# PyObject vs PyTypeObject

Tags: python, c, python-c-api

I am trying to build a Python-C interface, but when I looked at the source code, I am confused by `PyObject` and `PyTypeObject`. Can someone please explain the difference between them? It would be nice if someone could provide an example.

Comment: There's some great documentation inside the object.h header file: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Include/object.h

Comment: see also the actual documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

- `PyObject` is the analogous of `object` in Python
- `PyTypeObject` is the analogous of `type` in python

#### Let's check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/type.html#c.PyTypeObject) for `PyTypeObject`:

> The C structure of the objects used to describe built-in types.

This is the analogous to the *classes* as instances of `type` in python. This contains information about the type itself (e.g., the type name, docstring, the constructor function, etc.)

#### Now let's check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/structures.html#c.PyObject) for `PyObject`:

> All object types are extensions of this type....

This means you can reference any object as a `PyObject*` pointer. For example:

```c
PyObject *some_number = PyLong_FromLong(42);
```

> ... In a normal “release” build, it contains only the object’s reference count and a **pointer to the corresponding type object**.

As the **bold** part says, all `PyObject`'s contains a pointer to the **type** of that object which is a `PyTypeObject`.

In the example above, `some_number` is specifically a `PyLongObject` (which represents a Python integer object), and the structure that represents the integer type itself is `PyLong_Type` (which what you get from `some_number->ob_type`).